# Possible to Freeze Columns in a WPF ListView/GridView?

Tags: wpf, gridview, wpf-controls

I currently have a GridView inside a ListView.View.  The GridView columns will far exceed the width of the screen, so there will always be horizontal scrolling.

What I would like to do is to have certain columns always remain on the screen regardless of scrolling.  So the first x columns from the left are frozen (ala Excel), and the rest can scroll.

It does not need to be dynamic/user selected--I know in advance which columns need to be frozen.

Is this possible?

Comment: Deleted my answer. I was searching for GridView properties, but obviously followed the wrong link somewhere along the line.

Comment: I may have to switch to a DataGrid anyway as I am not finding this option for the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution would be to use two listviews next to each other. Left one would be for the frozen columns and right one would have horizontal scrolling enabled. If you need vertical scrolling you can wrap both listviews in a scrollviewer.

Comment: How you you control the headers from scrolling along with the data?

Comment: You mean when you use the vertical scroll the headers will scroll as well? Yes, that is why it was called a quick and dirty solution.